# Mac Subversion client that works with SvnBridge to TFS?

Tags: macos, cornerstone, svnbridge

We have a situation where a large number of .NET developers use Team Foundation Server 2010 for source control, and a small number of iOS developers (on Mac OS X, obviously) use Subversion.

In the hope of unifying these two systems, we have looked at using [SvnBridge](http://svnbridge.codeplex.com/) on the TFS server to allow SVN clients to connect to it.

Our initial tests (using TortoiseSVN on Windows) showed this working just fine.

However, the Mac users have not had much luck, trying a couple of different SVN clients.

Using the **Versions** SVN client, they are able to view the repository, check out, and check in; however, when viewing history, it does not show the name of user who committed a changeset, nor the comment attached to that changeset.

Using the **Cornerstone** SVN client, they could not even get the timeline to display, it just sat and span forever.

They do not wish to use Xcode's built-in SVN support as it is "crap" (their words, not mine).

Has anyone successfully used **Versions** or **Cornerstone** with SvnBridge? Did you encounter the issues I describe, and if so, how did you overcome them?

Or can anyone point me towards another Mac SVN client which they have used successfully with SvnBridge to TFS?

Comment: You will probably find that your question is closed because Stack Overflow is not a recommendation engine. You might want to try at http://apple.stackexchange.com instead.

Comment: @SSteve: I have reworded slightly. At its heart, this is not a "give me a recommendation" question, it's a "can this be made to work, and if so, how?" question

Comment: Does a command line client work? If so, you may try eclipse + javaHL and subclipse.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: thanks for the suggestion but the iOS developers do not use Eclipse and I certainly can't see them changing IDEs. Is it even possible to do iOS development with any IDE other than Xcode?

Comment: Not for developing, just as visual SVN client. Thought you are looking for an SVN Client.

Comment: @ChristianKuetbach: ah, gotcha. Sorry, I misunderstood. I'll run that idea by them.

Answer (score 0):

I have personally had this work as expected using the OS X native SVN cli ( command line interface ).

I don't use SVN GUI's, but I would envision that these clients ( Versions or Cornerstone ), and possible expected output they might be parsing for might more be the issue.